Running C# CustomAction in Wix4 Bundle project
We have a Wix 4.0.3 bundle project that creates an executable from a variety of MSI files. However, we need to run a C# method to insert some minor data in the accompanying database after the installation is complete.
Bundle.wxs looks something like this:
<?include Globals.wxi ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal" xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
    <Bundle ..>

        ...

        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\msi\file.msi" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
    <Fragment>
        <Binary Id="MyCustomActionDll" SourceFile="path\to\custom\actions\file.CA.dll" />
        <CustomAction Id="MyCustomAction" BinaryRef="MyCustomActionDll" DllEntry="AfterInstalled" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>

However, the custom action does not seem to get called during the installation.
Is there any way of accomplishing this using Wix bundle and how?
